# Does emacs support multi column editing?

Tags: emacs, text-editor

Emacs, like most text editors, supports editing from top to bottom:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

but, unlike Microsoft Word, I can't figure out how to edit in two columns:

```
col1    col2
word1   word2
word3
word4

Note: Editing in the first column does not change the spacing of the second.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fits your requirements, but you might take a look at [Two Column Editing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Two_002dColumn.html).

Comment: It looks like it... but when I try it, it wants to save the right buffer as a new file. Does this require me to save a file for each column?

Comment: I think you can "merge" the two buffers after editing. "When you have edited both buffers as you wish, merge them with <F2> 1 or C-x 6 1 (2C-merge). This copies the text from the right-hand buffer as a second column in the other buffer. To go back to two-column editing, use <F2> s."

Answer (score 6):

Org mode does. Just create a new file, call `M-x org-mode` and then paste this in:

```
* Look! A table! 
| col1   |  col2.  |
| word1 |  word2 |
| word3 |              |
| word4 |              |
```

Add as many columns as you want and this should behave the way you expect. Look at org-mode's documentation for the key bindings.
http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html

Comment: I thought of using ORG mode but it seems a little bit strange to me. I'm going to try the other two suggestion and use this as a fallback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for overwrite-mode. You should be able to toggle it with the `insert` key.

Comment: This is pretty basic, but it almost satisfies my needs. However, it's a huge pain when you're editing the second column and you hit C-n and it wraps to the front of the line.